# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de fecha en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando cambiar un formato de fecha de un string **(2016-06-09)** que envío desde [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) a una pagina [php](/questions/tagged/php) para colocarlo de una forma más entendible para el usuario, es decir, como  **(jueves, 9 de junio del 2016)**, pero no se como realizar el cambio.
He intentado con el [date_format](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php), como lo explican allí, pero la conversión es en inglés y la necesito en español.

Este es el código que he utilizado:

```
$date = date_create($fechaComite);
date_format($date, 'l jS F Y');
```

El resultado es **Friday, 9th June 2016**

Answer (score 10):

Para configurar tu zona horaria y el lenguaje debes de usar las siguientes funciones:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
// Unix
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
// En windows
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
```

Ahora puedes usar las siguientes funciones y obtener diferentes resultados.

```
$date= date('D, j \d\e F \d\e\l Y', strtotime($fechaComite));
//imprime Wednesday, 8 de March del 2017
```

Con Date() no funciona ya que este no permite cambio de lenguaje

```
$inicio = strftime("%A, %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($fechaComite));
// Imprime mi�rcoles, 08 de marzo del 2017
```

strftime en windows produce un error con las tildes pero en unix funciona bien.

Aqui tienes más ejemplos de como usar estas funciones Date y strftime

[Fechas en español](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=857:mostrar-fecha-en-espanol-php-setlocale-strftime-formato-datedefault-timezone-set-ejemplos-cu00831b&catid=70:tutorial-basico-programador-web-php-desde-cero&Itemid=193)

y tambien te dejo las configuraciones de SetLocale

[Setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: lo del problema del utf-8 en wndows lo corriges así: **echo utf8_encode($inicio)**

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es cambiar el formato "local" de tu aplicación, lo cual se realiza con el comando [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES'); // o el de tu país/idioma
$date = date_create($fechaComite);

// utilizar strftime para el manejo de 'locales'
strftime("%A, %d %B %G", strtotime($date->date));
```

Este locale debe estar instalado previamente en tu servidor, aquí el ejemplo para Ubuntu:

```
sudo locale-gen es_ES
```

---

**Edición:** Agrego el código que estoy utilizando para probar, el cual funciona.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.UTF-8');
$date = date_create('2016-06-09');
echo strftime("%A, %d %B %G", strtotime($date->date));
```

El resultado del echo es: `jueves, 09 junio 2016`

Comment: Al realizar esto me convierte la fecha como lo deseo pero muestra una fecha totalmente diferente, aparece  **jueves, 01 de enero del 1970** sin importar la fecha que le envíe, sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Por favor mira la edición que hice (incluir strtotime).

Comment: El error persiste, _para descartar_ verifique que el la variable que esta llegando sea de tipo String con la función [tag:php]  [gettype](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php) y asi es, sigue mostrando la misma fecha **jueves, 01 de enero del 1970**, no se cual pueda ser el error

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código con el cual estoy haciendo la prueba, el cual **funciona** perfectamente.

Comment: Lo intente de varias formas pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, desconozco cual pueda ser la razón, el hecho es que resolví hacerlo de forma más manual, hice un split de la fecha, cree un array con los meses y y le asigne estos valores a la función date de [tag:php] `strftime(date($date[2])." de ".$meses[date($date[1])-1]. " del ".date($date[0]))` algo similar a lo que hacen [aqui](https://lachabela.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/fechas-en-espanol-con-php-y-setlocale/) , muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: En mi caso el problema era no tener instalados los locales. OJO! en debian no funciona usando sudo locale-gen es_ES , hay que editar el archivo /etc/locale.gen descomentar los locales que quieras y después ejecutar locale-gen sin argumentos. Esto los instalará. Suerte.

Answer (score 1):

En caso de necesitar convertir el número de mes a letras, ésto te podría ayudar:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'esp_esp'); 
$mes = $_REQUEST['mes']; 
$mes = strtoupper(strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes)));
```

Agrego `esp_esp` ya que es la nomenclatura que usan los servidores basados en Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar fechas en un lenguaje local (que no sea Inglés) es necesario usar:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, ”es_ES”);
```

- En el primer parámetro se usa la constante LC_TIME, lo cuál le dice a
  PHP que quieres configurar el lenguaje usado en las fechas y horas.
- En segundo parámetro "es_ES", los primeros dos caracteres "es"
  indican el lenguaje que deseas usar y los últimos dos caracteres "ES"
  que están en mayúscula indican el país (en este caso España). En caso de que seas usuario de Windows debes usar "spanish" en lugar de "es_ES".

Colócalo preferentemente al inicio de tu archivo, aunque lo importante es que esté antes de tu función donde obtienes la fecha.

Adicionalmente, debes cambiar la función date() ya que no es "traducible" mediante este método, en su lugar debes usar strftime(), dejo un ejemplo de la traducción que buscas:

```
strftime("%A, %d de %B del %Y", $timestamp);
```

Te recomiendo consultar la página de PHP para más detalles sobre los parámetros para representar las fechas: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php

Comment: Al realizar esto me convierte la fecha como lo deseo pero muestra una fecha totalmente diferente, aparece **jueves, 01 de enero del 1970** sin importar la fecha que le envíe, sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Probablemente sea por que no estes usando un timestamp. Según el ejemplo de tu código podrías usar `$date->getTimestamp()` en el segundo parámetro de la función `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.UTF-8');
$date = "2017-03-25"; //es el campo que viene de MySQl aaaa-mm-dd
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B, %G", strtotime($date));
```

Este código devuelve martes, 25 de marzo, 2017

Answer (score 0):

```
function fechaHoraMexico($timestamp) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
    //$hora = strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", strtotime($timestamp));Descomentar en caso de requerir hora
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
    $fecha = utf8_encode(strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($timestamp)));
    return $fecha ;//$hora; concatenar con fecha para obtener fecha y hora
}
```

Puedes utilizar algo parecido a esto donde:
date_default_timezone_set muestra la hora según la zona que le definas, y setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish') muestra en español la fecha.

Answer (score -1):

Linux:

Primero verificar que se tenga la configuración regional:

```
locale -a
```

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
strftime("%A, %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($fecha));

Info:

https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-locales/