# Cambiar fecha a español con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**Quiero convertir la fecha en español pero me la muestra en ingles con el siguiente codigo**

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'esp_esp'); 
    $queryfecha = "SELECT fecha from 'tabla';";
    if ($sentencia2 = mysqli_prepare($con, $queryfecha)) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia2);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sentencia2, $fecha);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($sentencia2)) {
            $newDate = date("F d,Y", strtotime($fecha));
          echo $newDate;
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($sentencia2);
    }
```

Comment: Tendrás que crear tu propia clase utilitaria, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967).

Comment: que es eso de `esp_esp`? es un nuevo codigo de idioma?

Comment: @Jakala el tercer parámetro permite probar localismos http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php

Comment: ya, pero que localismo es `esp_esp` ?  entiendo el de `es_ES`, pero el otro no es de las normativas iso639 ni rfc1766... Por eso la pregunta

Comment: Al parecer es la nomenclatura que usan los servidores basados en windows https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53951/18182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu servidor no soporta `setlocale`, lo más sencillo es utilizar un array con los meses y reemplazar el mes.

```
$meses = array("mescero","Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");

echo $newDate = $meses[date("m", strtotime($fecha))]." ".date("d,Y", strtotime($fecha));
```