# Transformar fecha DateTime en palabras

Tags: php

Estoy intentando formatear la fecha de un DateTime en palabras

`23-06-2020` a `23 de junio de 2020`

He visto en la documentación de **php** algo parecido a esto, pero no consigo **ponerlo en español**

```html
$date = new DateTime('2020-06-23 10:00:00');
$newDate = $date->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

// Esto imprime Tuesday 23rd of June 2020 10:00:00 AM
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13456/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-el-formato-de-fecha-en-php

Comment: Es relativamente fácil crear tu propia clase utilitaria que extienda de `DateTime` ([ver un pequeño ejemplo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967)) o bien podrías usar la extensión internacional de PHP, el problema en este caso es que puede haber entornos donde dicha extensión no esté disponible.